# How to add parameters/variables in PHPMailer?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Below is the code snippet from my PHP file.  This code would essentially  send an email via PHPMailer.  What I was trying to do was get data from an HTML Form (Contact Us Page) and make the "From", "FromName", and "Body" fields dynamic based on user input.  The email is sending successfully. However, the user inputted data (From, FromName, and Message Body) in the Contact Us Page form is missing

```
<?php
...

$visitorEmail= $_POST['emailadd'];
$visitorName= $_POST['name'];

$mail->Username = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail-> Port = 465;
$mail->From = "$visitorEmail";                      
$mail->FromName = "$visitorName";

?>
```

Comment: Are you using `POST` method on your `<form>` element? Also there is no need to wrap variables in double quotes unless you're concatenating it with a string.

Comment: @Terry: Yes I am using the POST method on my <form> element.  I have been doing that for my other projects and it works, but this one does not seem to work

Comment: Some basic debugging will help here: try `var_dump($_POST);` to see if anything is actually being submitted.